# Python Bot Telepot error 'raise KeyError('No suggested keys %s in %s' % (str(keys), str(d)))'

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telepot

I have already implemented a lot of telegram bots with Telepot 12.7 and never had a single problem. Now, suddenly, after adding my bot to a group it started spamming this error message:

```
    raise KeyError('No suggested keys %s in %s' % (str(keys), str(d)))
KeyError: "No suggested keys ['message', 'edited_message', 'channel_post', 'edited_channel_post', 'callback_query', 'inline_query', 'chosen_inline_result', 'shipping_query', 'pre_checkout_query'] in {'update_id': 676740400, 'my_chat_member': {'chat': {'id': -500413139, 'title': 'NazTestGroup', 'type': 'group', 'all_members_are_administrators': True}, 'from': {'id': 172579176, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Nazareno Descanso', 'username': 'Descanso7', 'language_code': 'en'}, 'date': 1616661428, 'old_chat_member': {'user': {'id': 1684936782, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'telegram-reputation', 'username': 'reputationhmci_bot'}, 'status': 'member'}, 'new_chat_member': {'user': {'id': 1684936782, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'telegram-reputation', 'username': 'reputationhmci_bot'}, 'status': 'left'}}}"
```

The issue seems this one: https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/issues/184
but it is an old issue solved in 2016.
I tried adding 'new_chat_member' to the keymap and, with this fix, the bot starts but it is unresponsive, nothing passes to the "handle(msg)" method. It responds if you write to it in a private chat, but not in the group.

Here is the code with which I initialize the bot:

```
def handle(msg):
    global users_manager

    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id, msg)

    try:
        userid = get_userid(chat_id, msg)
        users_manager.add_user(userid)

        if content_type == "text" and msg["text"] == "/start":
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, f"Ciao! Sono reputation_bot, vi darò punti per ogni messaggio scritto "
                                     f"potendo guadagnare così livelli esclusivi!")
        else:
                users_manager.get_user(userid).add_points(1)
                check_if_lucky_message(userid, chat_id, msg)
                check_current_level(userid, chat_id, msg)
                print(users_manager.get_user(userid))
                pickle.dump(users_manager, open("score_dict.pkl", mode="wb"))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error:: {e}")
      

def main(argv):

    global bot
    global users_manager
    global levels_manager

    print(f"Bot started, token {TOKEN}")
    bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)

    levels_manager = LevelManager()
    users_manager = pickle.load(open("score_dict.pkl", mode="rb")) \
        if os.path.exists("score_dict.pkl") else UsersManager()

    print(levels_manager)
    print(users_manager)

    bot.message_loop(handle, run_forever=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: I created a new bot and now it is working. Don't know why.

Comment: I found the solution. The bot works in single chats and not in groups because in order to read ALL message, it has to be ADMIN of the group!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I have added by Bot into a group. To solve it, I have added 'update_id' in the list of keys inside _extract_message(update) function of the module 'loop.py', line 102.

```
def _extract_message(update):
    key = _find_first_key(update, ['update_id',
                                   'message',
                                   'edited_message',
                                   'channel_post',
                                   'edited_channel_post',
                                   'callback_query',
                                   'inline_query',
                                   'chosen_inline_result',
                                   'shipping_query',
                                   'pre_checkout_query'])
    return key, update[key]
```

I ran the bot again and it stops raising the exception. Then I remove my change and now everything works OK.

(I know, it's an ugly workaround but at least stop the issue)

Comment: I think the OP had already found the solution to the issue. See the comments.

Comment: This prevents the issue, however, there is another error popping up now: `argument of type int is not iteratable` - it's possible that telepot is broken with the new update

Comment: You can fix this by putting the `'update_id'` at the end of the list and not the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Faced with **the same problem**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\aio\loop.py", line 38, in run_forever
    self._update_handler(update)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\aio\loop.py", line 82, in <lambda>
    self._handle(_extract_message(update)[1]))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\loop.py", line 111, in _extract_message
    'pre_checkout_query'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 68, in _find_first_key
    raise KeyError('No suggested keys %s in %s' % (str(keys), str(d))
```

)

**Environment**:

Python 3.7.7

telepot==12.7

**Attempts**:

Using @Carlog suggestion raised for me the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\aio\loop.py", line 38, in run_forever
    self._update_handler(update)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\aio\loop.py", line 82, in <lambda>
    self._handle(_extract_message(update)[1]))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\aio\__init__.py", line 912, in handle
    id = calculate_seed(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\delegate.py", line 303, in f
    seed = fn(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\delegate.py", line 9, in w
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\telepot\delegate.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    if types == 'all' or msg['chat']['type'] in types
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

This is **hotfix** below for our bots until we have a better solution.

In the file **Lib\site-packages\telepot\loop.py** change the function **_extract_message**.

```
def _extract_message(update):

    key = _find_first_key(update, ['update_id',
                                   'message',
                                   'edited_message',
                                   'channel_post',
                                   'edited_channel_post',
                                   'callback_query',
                                   'inline_query',
                                   'chosen_inline_result',
                                   'shipping_query',
                                   'pre_checkout_query'])

    if key != 'update_id':
        return key, update[key]

    if 'message' in update.keys():
        return 'message', update['message']

    if 'my_chat_member' in update.keys():
        return 'message', {'message_id': update['update_id'], 
                            'from': update['my_chat_member']['from'], 
                            'chat': update['my_chat_member']['chat'], 
                            'date': update['my_chat_member']['date'], 
                            'text': f"It's update_id {update['update_id']}"
                        }
    raise Exception('The hotfix for update_id bug needs to upgrade')
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and fixed replacing **_find_first_key** function in ****init**.py** to the following:

```
def _find_first_key(d, keys):
for k in keys:
    if k in d:
        return k
return 'update_id'
```

If no hotfix seems to work for you, check the exact output of your error, get any valid key in your dictionary and use it as a return value for **_find_first_key**.
I only had to run my bot with these changes once, then it handled all the messages in the queue and got back to normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest fix I found was RUN  bot.getUpdates(offset=-1) in the code (Just before While Loop - Not in while loop). This entails that the program is restarted after a Group is removed or Added.
I have decided to modify the Telepot Library file: **init**.py at line 1191 (Added self.getUpdates(offset=-1)) as shown below. This seems to work automatically, but needs to be evaluated for all……..(I can now add and remove Groups at will)

`def get_from_telegram_server():
offset = None  # running offset
allowed_upd = allowed_updates
while 1:
try:
result = self.getUpdates(offset=offset,
timeout=timeout,
allowed_updates=allowed_upd)

```
                # Once passed, this parameter is no longer needed.
                allowed_upd = None

                if len(result) > 0:
                    # William Test for Group Add Error
                    self.getUpdates(offset=-1)
                    # No sort. Trust server to give messages in correct order.
                    # Update offset to max(update_id) + 1
                    offset = max([relay_to_collector(update) for update in result]) + 1
```

`